# Failed to print projection in GEE after sampleRegions

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sampling

I'm using the function `sampleRegions` to extract the `iamgecollection` values from the sample plot I imported. I assigned the projection at first when doing the `sampleRegions` , however, when I want to check the outcome projection, it doesn't work ***(xxx is not a function)*** when I printed any bands from the `iamgecollection` generated from the `sampleRegions`. Here I provide my code, and it's a bit long but the most important part starts from line 245.

How can I adjust my code?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d9dcaf2f3b647165e98b3722914ccb3e

```
//here is how I use the sampleRegions function
var s2_sample = s2L2017c1_6_Veg.sampleRegions({
  collection: trainingData,
  scale: 10,
  properties: ['AGB_DW'],
  projection: 'EPSG:3006'
});
```

````
//Here is the line with the error(line271)
//My target CRS is EPSG:3006
print(s2_sample.select("B5").projection())```
````

Answer (score 1):

The result of `sampleRegions` is a `FeatureCollection`. Each of the features in the collection does have a geometry that has a projection, but the collection *as a whole* does not remember what projection was used when creating it. So, there is no `projection()` method on `FeatureCollection`.

If you wanted to see the projection from one of the geometries, you could do that:

```js
print(s2_sample.first().geometry().projection());
```

However, that won't return the projection you chose — it seems to be always EPSG:4326. Evidently `sampleRegions()` doesn't generate points whose coordinates are *stored in* the projection you chose.

So, there doesn't seem to be a way to get what you want, but also, you shouldn't need it: just use the projection you already specified wherever you need it.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you for your answer. Does it mean that whether CRS I reproject, it cannot be used in analyzing? and it can only be converted when exporting the files? The reason I want to reproject first is that the CRS of my training dataset is in EPSG:3006, which is more precise in Nordic countries. If you know more about this or may know any sources of information, it would be great to see your further reply. Thank you!

Comment: @LinAnnie I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking. The purpose of `sampleRegions` is to return many independent point features, which have been _produced via_ a given projection but do not themselves _possess_ that projection, but that usually does not matter for points. If you want to _reproject an image_ there is [`ee.Image.reproject()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-reproject), but that is a very different operation even if it shares the similarity of sampling an image in a given projection.

Comment: @LinAnnie What is it that you were you trying to _achieve by_ fetching a projection from the _output_ of `sampleRegions`? If you want to verify that the points were made using the proper grid, then probably the best way to do that is to plot them on the map (and perhaps compare to a `reproject()`ed image)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. What I want to achieve is using `sampleRegions` to sample the pixel values for each band/index from the "s2L2017c1_6_Veg" where "trainingData" has data. The thing I cannot understand is even I used `reproject`, the imagecollection is still not being reprojected so there will be huge difference when doing sampling.  The thing that I really want to check is 1.whether GEE can select the corresponding points to the training data with the CRS I assign instead of the default one, that is the reason I printed out the projection for "s2_sample".

Comment: 2. If GEE can select the points in terms of the CRS I assigned, then why the outcome projection cannot be successfully printed out? If GEE cannot select the points with the CRS I want, then are there any other ways that I can do the `sampleRegions` function?

If I have already used the `reproject` for the `imageCollectio`, does it mean during the analysis (regression, machine learning..) will also be conducted with the CRS I define?

Comment: @LinAnnie "If GEE can select the points in terms of the CRS I assigned, then why the outcome projection cannot be successfully printed out?" Because the _points don't contain that information_. They are the individual outputs of the sampling process; the process itself is complete and not remembered. It's the same as the fact that the result of `3 + 4` is `7` — the `7` does not remember that it contained a `3`.

Comment: @LinAnnie I can't really help you further; I recommend that you post a new question in which you present the problem you now wish to solve ("huge difference when doing sampling") with the code that demonstrates the "huge difference", and examples of the wrong output. This attempt to fetch the projection from a collection will not help you solve that problem.